# Библиотека wget не отображает progress bar

Tags: python, python-2.x

При вызове `wget.download('http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3')` файл успешно скачивается, но progress bar не отображается. При вызове `wget.download('http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3', bar = wget.bar_thermometer)` файл успешно скачивается, но progress bar отображается как "[][][][][][]".
Также еще пробовал 
`wget.download('http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3', bar = wget.bar_thermometer(0, 100))`, но здесь возникает ошибка 
progress = bar_function(current_size, total_size, width)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, а сам файл сохраняется в формате .tmp. Как правильно вызывать `wget.download`, чтобы правильно отображался progress bar?

Comment: можно попробовать `wget.download('http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3', bar = wget.bar_adaptive)`

Comment: Пробовал, ничего не отображается.